# Azure API Management - Linking Subscriptions to our system

Tags: azure-api-management

We have an existing enterprise application that we'd like to add a new web API with Azure API Management in front.

Our system already has a concept of organizations. Each developer consuming our API will be interacting with a single organization. It seems that our organization is similar to a API Management Subscription. We're wondering if there's an easy way to a link between an subscription and our organization. We would create the subscriptions, we would not let developers sign up themselves. Is there a built-in way we can do a mapping e.g. a property that would could store our organization ID on the subscription? Or would we need to be that into our administration UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if there's an easy way to a link between an subscription and our organization.
```

AFAIK  **No** information is available regarding if there is a simple way to connect a subscription and an organization **but** i am just suggesting that you can try this In Azure API Management, you can create a mapping between your organisation and API management subscriptions by creating a custom subscription property and setting the organisation ID as its value.
These steps can be used to do this:

1. Locate your API Management instance in the Azure portal.
2. Choose "Subscriptions" from the menu on the left.
3. To add a new subscription, click "Add subscription".
   [image]
   can't proceed further due to restrictions so once check below steps may help.
4. Type a name for the subscription in the "Add subscription" dialogue box and choose the products or APIs you wish to include in the subscription.
5. Choose "Add property" from the "Custom properties" section.
6. Give the custom property a name, such as "Organization ID," and set the value to the ID of your organization.
7. Press "Create" to start a brand-new subscription.
   After creating this custom property, you may utilize it as necessary to map subscribers to your organization.
   Refer this add [custom properties](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/adding-custom-properties-to-apis/) to Api's document.
   It's important to note that this method is predicated on the idea that you have already created an organization in Azure AD and have its ID. Before employing this strategy, you must first establish an organization if you haven't already.

- you can also  use API Management Policies to enforce access restriction.
  Refer this [Document](https://www.cloudwithchris.com/blog/api-management-and-policies/)

Comment: Thanks Vijaya, I like your idea!

Comment: Do you know if these custom properties are publicaly available in any way, or are they hidden from API consumers?